# how to get/retrieve data based on current login user codeigniter but foreign key connected to another foregin key

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm still confused about fetch data from current user login session because it gives me all of the data and not only data that needed for this current user. I want to use id from table `guru` as current user session but `nilai` table already has foreign key from `mapel` and `g_mapel` which is for teacher data but with specific lesson while `g_mapel` has foreign key to `guru` which has complete data for the teacher biodata and I'm using this table as user login table that has password and email.

This is database for **guru**

```
CREATE TABLE `guru` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `namag` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `pass` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `nip` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `id_sekolah` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_role` INT(1) NOT NULL,
    `photo_gr` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `email_gr` (`email`),
    INDEX `FK_guru_sekolah` (`id_sekolah`),
    INDEX `FK_guru_role` (`id_role`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_guru_role` FOREIGN KEY (`id_role`) REFERENCES `role` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_guru_sekolah` FOREIGN KEY (`id_sekolah`) REFERENCES `sekolah` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=11
;
```

This is database for **g_mapel**

```
CREATE TABLE `g_mapel` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_guru` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_mapel` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `id_kelas` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_g_mapel_guru` (`id_guru`),
    INDEX `FK_g_mapel_mapel` (`id_mapel`),
    INDEX `FK_g_mapel_kelas` (`id_kelas`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_g_mapel_guru` FOREIGN KEY (`id_guru`) REFERENCES `guru` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_g_mapel_kelas` FOREIGN KEY (`id_kelas`) REFERENCES `kelas` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_g_mapel_mapel` FOREIGN KEY (`id_mapel`) REFERENCES `mapel` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=10
;
```

This is table for **mapel**

```
CREATE TABLE `mapel` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `nama_pel` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `id_kelas` INT(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_mapel_kelas` (`id_kelas`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_mapel_kelas` FOREIGN KEY (`id_kelas`) REFERENCES `kelas` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8
;
```

This is table for **nilai**

```
CREATE TABLE `nilai` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `id_mapel` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `angka` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    `id_siswa` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `FK_nilai_mapel` (`id_mapel`),
    INDEX `FK_nilai_siswa` (`id_siswa`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_nilai_mapel` FOREIGN KEY (`id_mapel`) REFERENCES `mapel` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_nilai_siswa` FOREIGN KEY (`id_siswa`) REFERENCES `siswa` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=19
;
```

This is the Model **nilai_model.php**

```php
function get_nilai_siswa()
    {
        $this->db->select('nl.id, sw.namas, mp.nama_pel, nl.angka, gr.namag, gr.id');
        $this->db->from('nilai nl');
        $this->db->join('siswa sw', 'sw.id=nl.id_siswa');
        $this->db->join('mapel mp', 'mp.id=nl.id_mapel');
        $this->db->join('g_mapel gm', 'mp.id=gm.id_mapel');
        $this->db->join('guru gr', 'gr.id=gm.id_guru');
        $this->db->where("gr.id", $this->session->userdata('guru_ses'));
        $this->db->distinct('nilai');
        return $this->db->get('nilai')->result_array();
    }
}
```

This is the Controller **nilai.php**

```php
function index($id)
    {
        $data['nilai'] = $this->Nilai_model->get_nilai_siswa($id);

        $data['_view'] = 'nilai/index';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    }
```

This is the view **index.php**

```php
<tr>
                            <th>No</th>
                            <th>Nama</th>
                            <th>Nilai</th>
                            <th>Nama Pelajaran</th>
                            <th>Nama Guru</th>
                            <?php if ($this->session->userdata('id_role') === '1') : ?>
                                <th>Pilihan</th>
                            <?php elseif ($this->session->userdata('id_role') === '2') : ?>
                                <th>Pilihan</th>
                            <?php else : ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        $no = 1;
                        foreach ($nilai as $n) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $no++; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $n['namas']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $n['angka']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $n['nama_pel']; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $n['namag']; ?></td>
                                <td>
```

I hope that someone can help me for this because I really don't understand about it even reading the manual from codeigniter itself

Comment: did you use `$this->db->last_query()`? so that you can see the query generated from that function get_nilai_siswa()

Comment: No it does nothing and how to put session correctly? Because I put this `$this->db->where("gr.id", $this->session->userdata('guru_ses'));` and It showed me nothing. I need this if someone can help ASAP

Comment: put `$last_query = $this->db->last_query()` below the `$data['nilai'] = $this->Nilai_model->get_nilai_siswa($id);` in your `index.php` so that you can check the query generated then print the `$last_query`

Comment: I got this `Message: Too few arguments to function Nilai::index(), 0 passed in C:\xampp\htdocs\raport1\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 532 and exactly 1 expected` when I put that. What's wrong with my codes?

Comment: did you try my answer?

Comment: Hey sorry I'll try it later and I'll tell you the results

Comment: I've tried it but still the same error. Should I put something on my index view? I mean how to pass id on view?

Comment: `your_url/index/12` '12' is the `$id`
and by the way, is your index has default display or just display all records?

Answer (score 0):

your function in `nilai_model.php` must have a parameter for the `$id` that's why you got an error of `Message: Too few arguments to function Nilai::` and also the `$this->session->userdata('guru_ses')` can cause error if it does not return an id and must change to `$id`

```
function get_nilai_siswa($id = null)
    {
        $this->db->select('nl.id, sw.namas, mp.nama_pel, nl.angka, gr.namag, gr.id');
        $this->db->from('nilai nl');
        $this->db->join('siswa sw', 'sw.id=nl.id_siswa');
        $this->db->join('mapel mp', 'mp.id=nl.id_mapel');
        $this->db->join('g_mapel gm', 'mp.id=gm.id_mapel');
        $this->db->join('guru gr', 'gr.id=gm.id_guru');
        $this->db->where("gr.id", $id);
        $this->db->distinct('nilai');
        return $this->db->get('nilai')->result_array();
    }
}
```

and in the `nilai.php` if you get no data then try to use the `$this->db->last_query()`

```
function index($id)
    {
        $data['nilai'] = $this->Nilai_model->get_nilai_siswa($id);
        var_dump($this->db->last_query()); //this one.. 
        $data['_view'] = 'nilai/index';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    }
```